# android studio XML layout isn't aligning

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have an XML script and in the android studio editor, the preview window shows the screen as it is supposed to look (see picture below). When running on the emulator it looks like all components shift position.

Here is the code for the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context="com.example.ansel.companionapp.Main_menu">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="113dp"
        android:src="@drawable/companionapp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/TPS_button"
        android:layout_width="146dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/infoText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/infoText"
        android:layout_marginStart="-25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:onClick="TPS"
        android:text="@string/ThirdPersonShooter"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/TDS_Button"
        android:layout_width="146dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TPS_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/infoText"
        android:layout_marginStart="-23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:onClick="TwoDS"
        android:text="@string/TwoDimensionalShooter"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my desired versus actual layout.

[image: Desired Layout]

[image: Actual layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed all the negative margins and alignings and added for all the views:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

So check this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context="com.example.ansel.companionapp.Main_menu">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/companionapp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/TPS_button"
        android:layout_width="146dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/infoText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:onClick="TPS"
        android:text="@string/ThirdPersonShooter"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/TDS_Button"
        android:layout_width="146dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TPS_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:onClick="TwoDS"
        android:text="@string/TwoDimensionalShooter"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. I spent way too long on this. what tags were causing the issues again? i couldn't spot them

Comment: The negative margins, android:layout_alignParentEnd="true", android:layout_alignStart="@+id/infoText"